# dotnet new Service Fabric Template

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Like with other templates for console, classlib, etc, is there any way to generate a new Service Fabric project, either with the dotnet command or some other command?

Comment: Using Visual Studio: File -> New Project -> Service Fabric Application?

Comment: As I said, from a command;)

Answer (score 0):

While researching the answer to the comment about non-Windows development, I stumbled across a generator in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-vs-code) I hadn't seen before describing how you might set up a Service Fabric application in VS Code.

Tweaking the prerequisites on the page, you'll need to install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) on your system and then the appropriate Yeoman generator(s) for your application from the command line:

```bash
npm install -g yo
npm install -g generator-azuresfjava
npm install -g generator-azuresfcsharp
npm install -g generator-azuresfcontainer
npm install -g generator-azuresfguest
```

The remainder of instructions on the page describe how to specifically develop using VS Code, but that's outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Not sure I understand this, cause that means you need Visual Studio to create a new Service Fabric project. What if you're on another platform other than Windows or macOS?

Comment: @JasonHunter I've found the appropriate tooling while looking around for the Linux approach and updated the answer.